# Lagrange multipliers for $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=x_1^2+\dots +x_n^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$, $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=x_1^2+\dots +x_n^2$ with the constraint $x_1+\dots +x_n=1$. Show that $f$ has a minimum point at $(\frac{1}n,...,\frac{1}n)$

Using the method of lagrange multipliers I found that the only critical point is $(\frac{1}n,...,\frac{1}n)$ but how can I determine that this point is in fact a minima? I would really appreciate yoru help

Comment: But in order to use the second derivative test I need to have that $f_{x_1}(\frac{1}n,...,\frac{1}n)=\dots=f_{x_n}(\frac{1}n,...,\frac{1}n)=0$ which is not the case

Comment: The Hessian matrix is twice the identity which is clearly positive definite.
But, an easier way is to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality which shows immediately that you have a global minimum.